# Prevent Gmail right-click from opening a New Message panel

Tags: gmail

If an email message contains an email address in the body, Gmail automatically converts it into a `mailto:` link, which is helpful.

And many times each day I've enjoyed being able to right-click a `mailto:` link in an email (within Gmail) and then click "Copy email address" in the context menu.

Then I can paste that email address into a program (such as when I want to search a database).

However, within the past month or so, I've noticed that I can't right-click and click "Copy email address" without Gmail then popping open a "New Message" panel and changing my current URL to have `?compose=new` at the end.

I wonder if it's related to [this month's rollout of new right-click features](https://www.engadget.com/2019/02/11/right-click-gmail/).

How can I disable it?

I'm tried of having to click the "Discard draft" trash can button so many times throughout the day.

Comment: Hmm… that’s strange; I don’t see this behaviour. Could it have anything to do with the mail handlers inside your browser? (In Chrome, check under _Settings_ → _Advanced_ → _Privacy and security_ → _Content Settings_ → _Handlers_.)

Comment: @Alex, I took your advice and removed Chrome as an email handler at `chrome://settings/handlers?search=handlers`, but that didn't have any effect on this problem. Plus, I've always had that as a handler, so something *else* must have changed in recent weeks. Thanks anyway.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/127028/186471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure when it was fixed, but today is the first day that I noticed *not* having this problem anymore.

Apparently Google finally changed their code.

People [complaining about it here](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/2698031?hl=en) seem to say that it was fixed 2019-05-04.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is caused by the fact that Gmail detects Chrome browser and ignores global browser setting which results in converting all email addresses by injecting **`mailto:`** address before each of them.

**`email@address.com`** is converted to **`mailto:email@address.com`** and therefore clicking on such address defaults to open compose window. Manually removing **`mailto:`** part from source code fixes the issue and further right clicking won't trigger the opening of compose window.

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Therefore, a solution would be to find some Chrome extension which is able to edit source code upon website load and remove all instances of **`mailto:`**

Another solution would be not clicking on an email address you want to copy, but highlight it with a mouse cursor and hitting **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>C</kbd>**

[image]

If you are with administrator access, this article states that **`mailto:`** scheme can be globally blacklisted: **https://www.chromium.org/administrators/url-blacklist-filter-format**

In other instances (outside of gmail.com) you need to delete Gmail from handlers at **`chrome://settings/handlers`** (but as already mentioned this won't work when on Gmail in Chrome)