# How do I prevent/stop Gmail's right-click opening a New Message panel?

Tags: gmail

[This question, asked by Ryan](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125519/prevent-gmail-right-click-from-opening-a-new-message-panel?newreg=883c6d2bbdef4492b0a72d6f857b3134), is the same issue I've been having.

What happens is when I right click an email address within an email message, Gmail opens a new message. I want to disable this. How do I do that?

NOTE:  this is using Gmail in Chrome.

I opened Gmail in Firefox and I don't have the problem. Here are some screenshots:

Email in Chrome:  https://www.screencast.com/t/ry6EoGUW1

Email in Firefox:  https://www.screencast.com/t/A8aMjekhinhr

While I can just use Firefox, I'd REALLY like to figure how to disable this in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, my work email is on G-Suite. (Had to confirm with our helpdesk ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is caused by the fact that Gmail detects Chrome browser and ignores global browser setting which results in converting all email addresses by injecting **`mailto:`** address before each of them.

**`email@address.com`** is converted to **`mailto:email@address.com`** and therefore clicking on such address defaults to open compose window. Manually removing **`mailto:`** part from source code fixes the issue and further right clicking won't trigger the opening of compose window.

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Therefore, a solution would be to find some Chrome extension which is able to edit source code upon website load and remove all instances of **`mailto:`**

Another solution would be not clicking on an email address you want to copy, but highlight it with a mouse cursor and hitting **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>C</kbd>**

[image]

If you are with administrator access, this article states that **`mailto:`** scheme can be globally blacklisted: **https://www.chromium.org/administrators/url-blacklist-filter-format**

In other instances (outside of gmail.com) you need to delete Gmail from handlers at **`chrome://settings/handlers`** (but as already mentioned this won't work when on Gmail in Chrome)

Comment: User0's answer is not correct. Amy is specifically talking about ***right-clicking*** an email address in Gmail — not left-clicking. The new right-click behavior is a recent change, and there is a Google Support thread about it here: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/2698031?msgid=2698031

Comment: Your answer would disable it for *both* left-clicking and right-clicking. That's not what she wants. She only wants to disable it for right-clicking. Popping a compose window on right-click is a new behavior that Google erroneously introduced, and we're all ready for them to fix it.